# Error saying "Module Not Found" when adding SPM which uses other SPMs as dependencies within itself

Tags: swift, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I have been creating a Swift Package Manager. It uses 2 other SPMs within itself. SPM compiles fine when compiled independently. As soon as the project is imported into an Xcode project I get a compiler error saying that:

```
No such module 'ModuleName'
```

> Note: The `ModuleName` in the above error corresponds to the package imported within the package that is being imported to my project.

I have been stuck on this for a pretty while now and have tried the following:

1. Removed and readded the SPMs to dependencies to my SPM, and then tried importing my SPM to my project (I did this before and after each of the other steps too).
2. Checked to see where these packages where being added as dependencies. It shows up in the SPM main target `Module` -> `Build Phases` -> `Link binary with libraries`. I additionally added it to the `Dependencies` section to see if it changes anything.
3. Tried adding SPMs to `ModulePackageDescription` target to `Dependencies` section.
4. Added the dependencies in the `Package.swift` file as follows.

```
dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
     .package(url: "package1_url", .branch("master")),
     .package(url: "package2_url", .branch("master"))
]
```

Adding this would import the other dependencies to my Xcode project. I don't exactly want this to happen because in case I try to use another version of the SPM that is being imported within my SPM, it would cause conflict between the two versions. But I'm willing to do this if it's the right way to go. But even adding `dependencies` in `Package.swift` didn't work for me. How would I resolve this issue? Let me know if anyone has faced the same issue.

Comment: Did you add dependencies to the target in targets array `byName` for example. In the Package.swift

Comment: Thank you for responding @EnesKaraosman. But, I did that. The issue with that is it doesn't allow me to add the dependant package individually to my project for usage within it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the libraries public classes also need to contain constructors?

public struct NumbersA {

```
public init () {    
}
```

}

also add them to the dependency  Package.swft->dependencies: ["NumbersA"]),